# Is the time complexity of `isInfixOf` in Data.ByteString.Char8 O(m * n)?

Tags: string, algorithm, haskell

From reading the relative source code,

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9.2.1/docs/src/Data-ByteString.html#isInfixOf ,

it seems that the `isInfix` algorithm is actually `O(m * n)`. But in fact, it runs much faster than `KMP` code by myself?

So is this algorithm actually `O(m * n)`, and how does `haskell` make this functional extremely efficient?

Comment: Asymptoticall complexity does not consider any constants, which may be more imporant in real-life scenarious than complexity itself. This may be the case - they have very small constants, you have big ones.

Comment: But in fact, use `isInfixOf` from Data.List will will not beat the KMP algorithm. So it seems that only change from String to ByteString will get huge increase in efficiency.  Why is that?

Comment: For example, notice that most `isPrefixOf`s will fail in the first few characters on non-degenerate data, so you will see approximately linear performance.  You could craft something that would cause quadratic performance but it would be quite special and not the usual case.

Comment: Oh, `String`s are linked lists, they are terribly inefficient as far as string representations go.  `ByteString` holding one byte per character in contiguous memory has a huge practical advantage.

Comment: I actually does not know the alghorithms, I just say, that in small numbers, the alghoritm with bigger complexity can be faster, due to big constants of other with smaller complexity.

Comment: @luqui: Yes. I know that. But in fact, use `isInfixOf` from Data.List will not get accept of the problem in time limit, but the KMP algorithm in haskell will get accept. So I believe there are some cases which will cause quadratic performance. But using `isInfixOf` from `Data.ByteString.Char8` can even run faster than KMP of String.

Comment: The complexity is not O(n^2), it's O(m*n) where m is the length of the needle and n is the length of the haystack.  If m is small then the brute force search will beat KMP, BM, and other clever algorithms. (To be pedantic, the complexity is also O(n^2) or O(n^3) or O(n^8), since O gives an upper bound.)

Comment: @augustss Sorry for the mistake in the statement. I actually want to mean O(m*n). The actually case is that there is at least one case which will cause the `isInfixOf` from Data.List to run exceed the time limit, while the KMP algorithm can finish within the limit. But the `isInfixOf` from `Data.ByteString.Char8` can run even faster than KMP.  I just want to know how can that be true, since it is still an O(m * n) algorithm. Does haskell do some low level efficiency tuning for Data.ByteString.Char?

Comment: I suspect you're just seeing the effects of much the much better data structure used for ByteString.  Much less memory traffic and better locality.

Comment: @augustss: Yes, very surprised to find out that only change from `[Char]` to `Data.ByteString` will get more than 60 times efficiency of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptoticall complexity does not consider any constants, which may be more imporant in real-life scenarious than complexity itself. This may be the case - they have very small constants, you have big ones.

By the definition, the bigger complexity is, when one function has in one point to infinity bigger value, even if you multiply other function by constant of any size.

However that "one point" may be huge.

For example if you have two alghoritms with this run-time : `1000000*n*sqrt(n)` and `n^2`, the complexity is bigger for `n^2`, but to achieve higher speed for first one, `n` must be higher than `1 000 000 000 000`. For smaller numbers `n^2` alghoritms is faster.

---

Therefore consider complexity by `But in fact, it runs much faster than KMP code by myself?` is not good approach.

Comment: There is at least one case which will cause quadratic time complexity, because the `isInfixOf` from Data.List can not finish in 5 seconds, while the KMP can finish in 0.26 seconds. But the `isInfixOf` from `Data.ByteString.Char8` can finish in 0.08 seconds. So there is at least 60 times difference in the efficiency of the two same algorithm, only the represent structures are different. Since the `isInfixOf` in Data.List is also very simple, I believe its algorithm complexity constant is also small, means change from `[Char]` to `ByteString` will get more than 60 times efficiency gain.